# Count character occurrences in a Python string

Tags: python, count

I want to get the each character count in a given sentence. I tried the below code and I got the count of every character but it displays the repeated characters count in the output. How to delete repeated character.

```
def countwords(x):
    x=x.lower()
    for i in x:
        print(i,'in',x.count(i)) 

x=str(input("Enter a paragraph "))
countwords(x)
```

My output is:

[image]

My output should not contain spaces count and repeated characters.. What to do....!!!

Comment: Check for spaces and exclude them? Store characters you've already counted and don't repeat them? Change the algorithm to iterate over the string only once adding up the counts that way (hint: `Counter`)? Have you really got no ideas?

Comment: Make sure you transcribe your indentation correctly when posting Python code. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code :

```
my_string = "count a character occurance"
my_list = list(my_string)
print (my_list)
get_unique_char = set(my_list)
print (get_unique_char)

for key in get_unique_char:
    print (key, my_string.count(key))
```

Comment: You don't need to create the intermediary `my_list` (strings are iterable), and spaces will still be included in your output.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different approaches, most hinted at by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s comment, but I'd suggest a simple [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set).

The set approach, along with a few others are included below:

```
# An approach using a set
def countwords_set(s):
    for c in set(s):
        if c == ' ': continue
        print(c, 'in', s.count(c))

# An approach using a standard dict
def countwords_dict(s):
    d = dict()
    for c in s:
        if c == ' ': continue               # Skip spaces
        d[c] = d.get(c,0) + 1               # Use the .get method in case the 
                                            #   key isn't set

    for c,x in d.items():                   # Display results
        print(c, 'in', x)


# An approach using a defaultdict (from the collections module)
def countwords_ddict(s):
    from collections import defaultdict     # Typically, imports go at the top

    d = defaultdict(int)

    for c in s:
        if c == ' ': continue
        d[c] += 1

    for c,x in d.items():
        print(c, 'in', x)


# An approach using a Counter (from the collections module)
def countwords_counter(s):
    from collections import Counter         # Typically, imports go at the top

    counter = Counter(s)

    # Counters can be accessed like dicts
    for c,x in counter.items():
        if c == ' ': continue
        print(c, 'in', x)


# User input and comparison
s = str(input("Enter a paragraph "))
s = s.lower()

countwords_set(s)
print("---")

countwords_dict(s)
print("---")

countwords_ddict(s)
print("---")

countwords_counter(s)
print("---")
```

The output is the essentially the same for each approach, although the order of the characters may differ since Python dictionaries are unordered.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict.

```
def countwords(x):
    d = dict()
    x=x.lower()
    for i in x:
        if i in d.keys():
            d[i] = d[i] +1;
        else:
             d[i] = 1;

     for i in d.keys():
          print i + " " + d[i]
```

Comment: Note that this becomes much simpler with `dict.setdefault`, or a `defaultdict`, or a `Counter`, or just rearranging your `if` and `else` conditions. Also you don't need to specify `.keys()` for the comparison or loop. Also also you can use augmented assignment. Basically the idea is right, but the implementation could be much better.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : I felt a simpler implementation is a better way to make a newbie understand.

Comment: Well it might be if you'd included any explanation of what was going on, rather than just dumping an implementing on a lazy user.

Answer (score 0):

Or use numpy with this one-liner

```
np.unique(np.array(list('count these characters')), return_counts=True)
```