# How to restrict the amount of characters in a Text() Tkinter box?

Tags: python, tkinter, character-limit

I've looked for many answers but have only found ones that show how to do it for Entry(). Here I would like to limit the number of characters to 200 but I don't know how to do so.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x600")

msgText = Text(window, width = 42, height = 13, font = ('Arial', 10), wrap=WORD)
msgText.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 30, pady = 5)

window.mainloop()
```

Can anyone help me by either showing me how to do this or linking a question like this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454138/count-character-occurrences-in-a-python-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example using a `Text` widget with a character count function bound to `'<KeyPress>'` (a.k.a. `'<Key>'`) and `'<KeyRelease>'` events. Binding to both events (in my experience) keeps the count accurate in situations where keys are held/repeating and so on.

Note: I've made a few minor changes for better adherence to best-practices.

```
import tkinter as tk


def char_count(event):
    """This function allows typing up to the character limit and allows deletion"""
    count = len(msg_text.get('1.0', 'end-1c'))
    if count >= CHAR_LIMIT and event.keysym not in {'BackSpace', 'Delete'}:
        return 'break'  # dispose of the event, prevent typing


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("800x600")
CHAR_LIMIT = 200

# PRO TIP: don't use camelCase for Python variable names
msg_text = tk.Text(window, width=42, height=13, font=('Arial', 10), wrap=WORD)
msg_text.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=30, pady=5)

msg_text.bind('<KeyPress>', char_count)
msg_text.bind('<KeyRelease>', char_count)

window.mainloop()
```

Note that this will block *all* key presses other than `Delete` or `BackSpace` once the character limit is reached! I'll leave it to you to figure out how to discriminate which keypresses are allowed (hint: the string class `str` has a number of methods for this sort of thing)

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a function that counts the number of key entries and call that function after each entry.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x600")

msgText = Text(window, width = 42, height = 13, font = ('Arial', 10), wrap=WORD)
msgText.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 30, pady = 5)
def count_entries(e):
    entries = msgText.get('1.0',END)
    count = len(entries)
    # Probably want to count the number of line breaks (\n) and remove them from the count
    if count > 200:
        msgText.delete('end-2c')
msgText.bind('<KeyRelease>',count_entries)


window.mainloop()
```

Frankly, I'd consider using a different widget such as Message

Comment: `Message` has been deprecated in favor of `Label`, and doesn't accept user input at any rate.